# How Secret is splitted in Shamir Algorithm

Tags: encryption, cryptography, secret-sharing

I have been reading about the Shamir Secret Sharing algorithm. While researching I am still not sure how a secret is split.

So let's suppose we follow example given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing). 
The secret is `1234` and we choose random numbers `a1 = 166` and `a2 = 94`, so the secret polynomial is:

```
f(x) = 1234 + 166*x + 94*x^2
```

Now I get the following points:

**(1,1494); (2,1942); (3,2578); (4,3402); (5,4414); (6,5614)**

But I do not understand where these (bold) points come from. If I have another polynomial, how I would create the new set of points?

I know there is a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing) written, but considering that I don't understand that Alien Math at all, can you describe the method in easy language?

Comment: I know this was voted to be moved to crypto, but I'm not sure it would be accepted. This is a pure maths question, and it is explained on the very wiki page that is linked. You do not need to understand the crypto, you just need to understand the basic math.

Comment: `We construct 6 points D_{x-1}=(x, f(x)) from the polynomial ...`

Comment: why everybody got crazy with this question. I had confusion I asked. What is the purpose of this forum? to degrade others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the evaluations of the polynomial. `f(1) = 1494,  f(2) = 1942, f(3) = 2578, f(4) = 3402, f(5) = 4414, f(6) = 5614`